# How to train and predict in parallel via Spark MLlib?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I have to solve regression problem for different restricitons. There is a bunch of criteria and rules for them, I have to build model and make predictions for each, combine all and save.
So, now my solution looks like:

```
criteria2Rules: List[(String, Set[String])]

var result: RDD[(Id, Double)] = sc.parallelize(Array[(Id, Double)]())
criteria2Rules.foreach {
  case (criterion, rules) =>
    val trainDataSet: RDD[LabeledPoint] = prepareTrainSet(criterion, data)
    val model: GradientBoostedTreesModel = buildModel(trainDataSet)
    val predictionDataSet = preparePredictionDataSet(criterion, data)
    val predictedScores = predictScores(predictionDataSet, model, criterion, rules)
    result = result.union(predictedScores)
}
```

It works almost nice, but **too slow** for the reason GradientBoostedTreesModel training not so fast, especially in case of big amount of features, samples and also quite big list of using criteria. 
I suppose it could work better, if Spark will train models and make predictions in parallel.

I've tried to use a relational way of data operation:

```
val criteria2RulesRdd: RDD[(String, Set[String])]

val cartesianCriteriaRules2DataRdd = criteria2RulesRdd.cartesian(dataRdd)
cartesianCriteriaRules2DataRdd
  .aggregateByKey(List[Data]())(
    { case (lst, tuple) => lst :+ tuple }, { case (lstL, lstR) => lstL ::: lstR}
  )
  .map {
    case (criteria, rulesSet, scorePredictionDataList) =>
      val trainSet = ???
      val model = ???
      val predictionSet = ???
      val predictedScores = ???
  }
  ...
```

but it inevitably brings to situation when one **RDD** is produced inside another **RDD** (GradientBoostedTreesModel is trained on RDD[LabeledPoint]) and as far as I know it's a bad scenario.

Is there any way to use Spark MLlib in parallel way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked the same question in the Spark User Mailing List, and got the answer:

"If you have a big cluster, you can trigger training jobs in different threads on the driver. Putting RDDs inside an RDD won't work. Simple example:

```
(0 until 10).par.foreach { i =>
  val n = sc.parallelize(0 until 1000000).count()
  println(s"$i: $n")
}
```

"